# Automate CI release for Xamarin iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin, release, release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am looking to automate the CI build for Xamarin iOS app directly to the App Store. VSTS does not have any tools for it yet.
I tried using fastlane.tools but it is not supporting Xamarin. Can I add any better steps in the VSTS to automate the release of Xamarin iOS app into the appstore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into Bitrise.io. I blogged about it a view month ago [here](http://blog.cayas.de/continuous-integration-and-deployment-with-bitrise) and can highly recommend it.

Comment: Could you add an example of how it would be used

Comment: Check out his blog. It has few very simple steps to set up.

Answer (score 3):

To accomplish this I used [fastlane tools](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/), [cake build](http://cakebuild.net/), and [cake.xamarin](https://github.com/Redth/Cake.Xamarin).  Cake was used in place of [gym](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/gym).  Cake allows you to build on either platform without fastlane since bash and powershell scripts are provided.  [More cake Xamarin info](http://redth.codes/would-you-like-some-csharp-in-your-cake/).

To build Android look at [AndroidPackage](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.xamarin/c86482e2/3ecac89e).  It will build release and create, sign, and zipalign the apk.

To build iOS look at [DotNetBuild](http://cakebuild.net/dsl/dotnetbuild).  `Platform`, `Target`, `BuildIpa`, `CodesignKey`, and `CodesignProvision` can be passed using `settings.WithProperty("arg","value")`.

Once the cake build scripts are working, they can be used in a lane instead of gym: `sh ".././build.sh -s \"../build.cake\" -t \"iOS\""`

I'm not sure of your vsts setup but I setup a MAC build server with the [vsts-agent](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent) and was then able to add a command line step to a build definition and call the appropriate fastlane lane.  So building from the definition or command line was the same.  Then additional things can be added to the build definition as needed like slack integration, etc.

Initially, I had the build working without fastlane or cake with vsts alone but preferred being able to build from the commandline and then call that from a build step.

Update:

> 1. Use fastlane with VSTS and Xamarin.iOS ?

Fastlane tools are written in ruby to automate things, like calling xcode to build or google play API's to deploy.  Fastlane doesn't specifically have an action for msbuild so I used cake build for that since the calls in cake call msbuild or xbuild depending on the platform.

> 2. When you said you had build working without fast lane or cake, did you also had it working for release management?

If you go to visualstudio.com and create a build definition, you can select a Xamarin Android or iOS template and then fill in the blanks.  The steps call nuget, build, sign, etc.  The same things cake build is doing.

For release management, [spaceship](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship), [pilot](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/pilot), or [supply](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/supply) can be used and added after the build happens or you could have a separate "lane" that calls them and call that from vsts.

It's easier to get the build working and then from the command line play with spaceship, pilot, or supply.  Then you can tweak the different config files for them and get them working how you like, then add them to a lane.

Comment: I am using VSTS with MacInCloud. Can you be little more specific how you were able to 
1. Use fast lane with VSTS and Xamarin.iOS ? I though Xamarin is not supported by Fastlane.
2. When you said you had build working without fast lane or cake, did you also had it working for release management? With VSTS I can have a successful build but I want to automate the release till app store.

Comment: Derek,

I am new to this so please bear with me. 
1.Can you please tell me how did you add spaceship, pilot and various other tools via VSTS ?? I did not find any special steps or the plugin in the marketplace to add them. 
2.What do you mean by have separate lane-call them-Call that from VSTS?How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Derek, do you have any information about using Jenkins with cake to build xamarin android and ios?

Comment: Once you are able to build with cake, you should be able to use any tool because you're just calling fastlane, which calls cake, or cake itself. http://blog.zuehlke.com/en/continuous-integration-for-mobile-apps-with-fastlane-and-jenkins/